# Perl Array contains itself?

Tags: arrays, perl

I do not understand what is going on with this short segment of code.

I have put the output and comments about it in the middle, after the print statements which produce it.

```
my @regions = (
0,
1,
2,
[ 0, new Point(3,1), new Point(3,2), new Point(3,3) ],
4,
5 );

$reg1 = 3;
print "1: $regions[$reg1] \n";

@reg1 = @{regions[$reg1]};
print "2: $reg1[0]\n";
print "3: $reg1[0][1]\n";
print "4: ", Point::stringPoint($reg1[0][1]), "\n";

# HERE IS THE OUTPUT from the above print statements, with comments about my confusion appended
1: ARRAY(0xe8b0e0)      # ok - element 3 of @regions is an array, as expected.
2: ARRAY(0xe8b0e0)      # It appears to be an array of one element, which is itself. ???
3: Point=HASH(0xfda5e0) # We have go 'down' one more level to get what we want - that makes no sense
4: 3,1                  # Yes, there it is

package Point;
sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = {
      x => shift,
      y => shift
   };
   bless $self, $class;
   return $self;
}

sub stringPoint
{
 my $p = shift;
 return "$p->{x},$p->{y}";
}

" Code related to new question (with output) " ;
```

The *real* question I have is this:
How to work directly and conveniently with an array,
which is inside another array (not a copy of it) ?
Is the only way to do that by (always) de-referencing a reference?
Such as in the two non-working examples which follow.

Here is what I tried:

```
my $ref1 = \@{$regions[3]};

@{$ref1}[2] = new Point(4, 5);  # changes original array
print1Region(3, $ref1);
# OUTPUT = (3,1) (4,5) (3,3)

my @arr1 = @{$ref1};
$arr1[1] = new Point(2,6);  # does not
print1Region(3, $ref1);
# OUTPUT = (3,1) (4,5) (3,3)

$ref1[0] = new Point(1,4);  # does not
print1Region(3, $ref1);
# OUTPUT = (3,1) (4,5) (3,3)
```

Comment: `@{regions[$reg1]}` - Sure about that? Try changing it to `@{$regions[$reg1]}`.

Comment: @Shawn - that change makes THIS program work more sensibly, but let me go back to the 'unsimplified' version to see why I didn't use your construct in the first place.

Comment: @Shawn - ok I think I got it ... it had to do with passing these things to subroutines, and getting the use of \ right to get references when needed. Thanks for that bit of help.

Comment: Note that if you `use warnings;` like you always should, perl would have warned you abut that line.

Comment: (What I don't understand, and why I didn't make an actual answer, is why that's being treated as an array slice and not a syntax error)

Comment: @Shawn  Let's just forget about @{regions[$reg1]}. I've added a follow-up set of examples, which would help me understand all this better.

Answer (score 4):

`@{regions[$reg1]}` is a weird and undocumented way of writing `@regions[$reg1]`. (It's a syntax documented for use in double-quoted string literals.)

`@regions[$reg1]` is an array slice with one element, which is a weird way of writing `$regions[$reg1]`.

So you aren't getting the first element of the array referenced by `$regions[$reg1]` as you think you are; you are simply getting the first element of `@regions`.

---

Let's look at

```
my $ref1 = \@{$regions[3]};
@{$ref1}[2] = new Point(4, 5);
```

**Problem #1**

`\@` "cancel out", so

```
my $ref1 = \@{$regions[3]};
```

is just a complicated way of writing

```
my $ref1 = $regions[3];
```

(Ok, that's not quite true because the former autovivifies, but that's not relevant here.)

**Problem #2**

Again you're using an array slice of one element. ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;` and heed the warnings!

```
@{$ref1}[2] = new Point(4, 5);
```

should be

```
${$ref1}[2] = new Point(4, 5);
```

which is more cleanly written using the "arrow notation".

```
$ref1->[2] = new Point(4, 5);
```

**Problem #3**

Finally, don't use indirect method calls. They cause issues.

```
$ref1->[2] = new Point(4, 5);
```

should be

```
$ref1->[2] = Point->new(4, 5);
```

**Conclusion**

```
my $ref1 = \@{$regions[3]};
@{$ref1}[2] = new Point(4, 5);
```

should be written as

```
my $ref1 = $regions[3];
$ref1->[2] = Point->new(4, 5);
```

Without the variable, this would be

```
$regions[3]->[2] = Point->new(4, 5);
```

or just

```
$regions[3][2] = Point->new(4, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you for all that. I think the way to go will be $ref1->[subscript].  The whole reason for this question in the first place was that I didn't want to have write $regions[$reg1] all the time - it's not just this one line of code, it's a whole section, involving two of them, with many uses of the elements of those arrays.  Hence the desire for a temporary variable for the element of regions.